# proof that the holomorfic function f is constant under condition

Tags: complex-analysis

We have a holomorphic function $ f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C} $, and $ \Omega $ is a connected open group.

The closed disk $D(a,r)$ is contained in $\Omega$.  Let $ a, b \in \mathbb{C} $.

$ r \in \mathbb{R}_*^+ $

$ \theta_0 \in \mathbb{R} $

We define the circle $C_{a,r}$ as $$C_{a,r}=\{ a + re^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C}, \qquad \theta \in \mathbb{R} \}$$ and the straight $D$ as $$ D = \{ b + t e^{i\theta_0}: t \in \mathbb{R} \}. $$We suppose that $f(C)$ is contained in $D$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "put $a$ and $b$ of $C$"?

Comment: @AhaanRungta I'm guessing it means "let $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$."

Comment: yes  i  means let a,b∈C.

Comment: Edited to use $\LaTeX$.

Comment: is this Theorem is true : " if the holomorphic function f  is constant on the perimeter of a closed disk then he is constant over the entire disk"

Answer (score 0):

After composing $f$ with a suitable rotation and translation, we obtain a function that maps the circle $C$ into the real line $\mathbb R$. [This composite function is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255848/proof-that-an-analytic-function-that-takes-on-real-values-on-the-boundary-of-a-c), so $f$ is too.

Comment: but is thisTheorem is true :
" if the holomorphic function f is constant on the perimeter of a closed disk then he is constant over the entire disk"

Comment: @omran Yes. A holomorphic function on the neighborhood of a disk is uniquely determined by the values it takes on the boundary of the disk.