# Prove that $f$ is constant if $f$ is real when $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that if $f$ is real when $|z|=1$, then $f$ must be a constant function.

I honestly do not know how to do this problem, consider using Schwarz's lemma, but do not get anywhere.

Comment: Same question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226786/let-fz-be-entire-function-show-that-if-fz-is-real-when-z-1-then-f?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is a holomorphic function that equals $f(z^{-1})$ on the unit circle.  Therefore these functions are equal everywhere.  In particular $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore constant.

Comment: Nice proof ! :)

Comment: Very good proof!

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* If $f=u+iv$ is real, then $v=0$ on the unit circle. Now use the maximum principle for harmonic functions.