# Proving a holomorphic function is constant on an open connected set under certain conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ be an open and connected set, such that $\overline{D_1} \subset \Omega$. Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function with $f(z) \in \mathbb R$ for all $z$ such that $|z|=1$. Show that $f$ is constant.

I couldn't do much of the problem. I've defined the function $e^{if(z)}$. So, for $z : |z|=1$, $e^{if(z)} \in \partial D_1$. I don't know if this is of any help. I would appreciate suggestions, maybe defining this function is not useful.

Addition from editing:

From what I've seen here [Let $f(z)$ be entire function. Show that if $f(z)$ is real when $|z| = 1$, then $f(z)$ must be a constant function using Maximum Modulus theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226786/let-fz-be-entire-function-show-that-if-fz-is-real-when-z-1-then), using the maximum modulus principle, if $e^{if(z)}$ is non-constant on $D_1=\{|z|<1\}$, then $e^{if(z)}$ attains its maximum and minimum on $\partial D_1$. If we consider $e^{if}$ and $e^{-if}$, then $|e^{if(z)}|=1=|e^{-if(z)}|$ for all $z : |z|=1$. But then $$(1) \space |e^{if(z)}|\leq 1, |z|<1,$$ and $$(2) \space |e^{-if(z)}|\leq 1, |z|<1$$.

From (1) and (2) it follows $|e^{if(z)}|=1$ for all $z :\{|z|\leq 1\}$, which means $e^if$ is constant on $D_1 \implies f$ is constant on $D_1$.

I don't see how can I deduce from here that $f$ is constant on $\Omega$ just by the fact that $f$ is constant on $D_1$.

Comment: Although the duplicate contains the assumption that $f$ is entire, it is not actually used in the answers.

Comment: Concerning your last step: $f$ is constant on $D_1$ which means that $|f|$ has a local maximum in the interior of $\Omega$. It follows from the maximum modulus principle that $f$ is constant on $\Omega$.

Comment: Now I got it, thanks!